# AWS resource is getting created before IAM role hence failing for missing role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to create endpoint in sagemaker using. below is serverless.yaml file
I am getting

```
PocModelEndPointRole" exists and that its trust relationship policy allows the action "sts:AssumeRole" for the service principal
```

After investigation stack event
I see

```
2022-05-25 02:03:03 UTC+0530    RModelEndpointModel CREATE_FAILED   Could not access model data at s3://my-bucket/output/byom_poc/gre_score_knn.tar.gz. Please ensure that the role "arn:aws:iam::19:role/PocModelEndPointRole" exists and that its trust relationship policy allows the action "sts:AssumeRole" for the service principal "sagemaker.amazonaws.com". Also ensure that the role has "s3:GetObject" permissions and that the object is located in us-east-2. (Service: AmazonSageMaker; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 243d62e4b-a7a1-488a-b89e-8aa0fb486296; Proxy: null)
2022-05-25 02:03:02 UTC+0530    ServiceNotificationTopic    CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  Resource creation Initiated
2022-05-25 02:03:02 UTC+0530    ModelEndpointRole   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  Resource creation Initiated
2022-05-25 02:03:01 UTC+0530    ServiceNotificationTopic    CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2022-05-25 02:03:01 UTC+0530    RModelEndpointModel CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2022-05-25 02:03:01 UTC+0530    ModelEndpointRole   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2022-05-25 02:02:57 UTC+0530    byom-pc-dev CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  User Initiated
```

### Serverless.yaml

```
resources:
  Resources:
    RModelEndpointRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        Path: /
        RoleName: ${self:custom.modelEndpointRoleName}
        PermissionsBoundary: ${self:provider.rolePermissionsBoundary}
        ManagedPolicyArns:
          - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
          - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLogsFullAccess"
          - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchEventsFullAccess"
          - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSageMakerFullAccess"
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - events.amazonaws.com
                  - states.amazonaws.com
                  - sagemaker.amazonaws.com
              Action:
                - sts:AssumeRole
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: ${self:custom.modelEndpointRoleName}
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: "2012-10-17"
              Statement:
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                    - s3:List*
                    - s3:Get*
                    - s3:Put*
                  Resource:
                    - "arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.deploymentBucket}/*"
                    - "arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.deploymentBucket}"
    RModelEndpoint:
      Type: "AWS::SageMaker::Endpoint"
      Properties:
        EndpointConfigName:
          !GetAtt RModelEndpointConfig.EndpointConfigName
    RModelEndpointConfig:
      Type: "AWS::SageMaker::EndpointConfig"
      Properties:
        ProductionVariants:
          - InitialInstanceCount: 1
            InitialVariantWeight: 1.0
            InstanceType: ml.t2.large
#            ModelName: "myrmodel"
#            VariantName: "test1"
            ModelName: !GetAtt RModelEndpointModel.ModelName
            VariantName: !GetAtt RModelEndpointModel.ModelName
    RModelEndpointModel:
      Type: "AWS::SageMaker::Model"
      Properties:
          PrimaryContainer:
            Image: ${self:custom.sagemakerRExecutionContainerURI}
            Mode: SingleModel
            #ModelDataUrl: !Sub s3://${AppBucket}/${ModelDataPath}
            #ModelDataUrl: s3://${self:custom.deploymentBucket}/${self:service}/${self.custom.ModelDataPath}
            ModelDataUrl: "s3://my-bucket/output/byom_poc/gre_score_knn.tar.gz"             
          
          ExecutionRoleArn: "${self:custom.modelEndpointRoleARN}"
```

Error that i am getting

```
Serverless Error ---------------------------------------
 
  An error occurred: RModelEndpointModel - Could not access model data at s3://my-bucket/output/byom_poc/gre_score_knn.tar.gz. Please ensure that the role "arn:aws:iam::19:role/PocModelEndPointRole" exists and that its trust relationship policy allows the action "sts:AssumeRole" for the service principal "sagemaker.amazonaws.com". Also ensure that the role has "s3:GetObject" permissions and that the object is located in us-east-2. (Service: AmazonSageMaker; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 83d62e4b-a7a1-488a-b89e-8aa0fb486296; Proxy: null).
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this [link](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/1981)

below code worked for me.

```
RModelEndpointModel:
   DependsOn: ModelEndpointRole
   Type: "AWS::SageMaker::Model"
```